# How do you use the search method in javascript in an if statement?

Tags: javascript

I have an if statement that I want to execute if a certain variable does not have the `<br/>` element in it. How would you do this?

I tried

```
var str = "hello<br/>goodbye";
if( str.search("<br/>") == false) {
//execute certain code
}
```

but this did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The search() function returns the position that the match was found at (if any).  If no match was found, it returns -1.  So you want

```
var str = "hello";
if( str.search("e") <0) { //no match
//execute certain code
}
```

Also note that the search parameter is a regular expression; when you try to search for an HTML tag that may become relevant.

Comment: It works the exact same way. It just return s the starting position in the string of whatever you pass in as a parameter. The same code should work.

Comment: You should just be able to put `"<br/>"` where you currently have "e", but you might want to use a more sophisticated regex if, for example, you want to match `"<br />"` or `"<br style='clear:all' />"` and so forth.

Comment: What's the advantage of `.search()` over `.test()`?

Comment: @Peter: in this instance, there isn't one.  Passing a string literal to *search()* implies a lack of understanding of the *search()* method.

Answer (score 6):

You can use regexes also:

```
if (/e/.test(str)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: It's ironic that your post was down voted when it's actually more appropriate in this scenario than *search()*.  *test()* works in a similar way to *search()*, except it returns a boolean for a successful match, rather than the matching substring's position. +1 to even it out.

Answer (score 1):

Don't pass a string literal as the argument for *search()*.  Any non-regular expression passed to *search()* will be used to create a regular expression and any "special" characters in it will lose their literal meaning.  For example:

```
"Hello. Goodbye".search(".")
```

Will return `0`, not `5` where the `.` character is.  This is because `.` has a special meaning in a regular expression and will match any character except for a newline.

You actually require the [*indexOf()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method, which does **exactly** the same thing but takes a string as its argument, and returns the position of the substring match within the string:

```
var str = "hello<br/>goodbye";
if(str.indexOf("<br/>") == -1) { // String not found
    //execute certain code
}
```

More information at the [MDC documentation for search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search).

Answer (score 0):

The `search` function returns an index.  It will be `>=0` if the value is found

```
if ( str.search("e") >= 0 ) { 
  // the string matches
}
```

`search` documentation

- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp

Your original question though mentions determining if the value does not have the `<br/>` element in it.  Can you be a little more specific on this point.  In particular what is the value: DOM element, string, etc ...